# How to produce white space for all text lines of an environment?

Tags: environments, line-spacing

How can I produce whitespace before each line of an environment. If I have the following command in the preamble

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\vspace{3mm}\hspace{0.5cm}\noindent\ignorespaces\small\texttt}
{\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend\vspace{0.5mm}}
```

and in the text:

```
\begin{myenv}
hello \\
world
\end{myenv}
```

this produces whitespaces only for the first line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, as I've done it just now, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. 

It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Speravir and Canageek, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you might be interested in using a combination of `\obeylines` (so you don't have to manually break the line) and `\doublespacing` (provided by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,setspace}
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\par\hrulefill\doublespacing\obeylines}
{\hrulefill\par\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{myenv}
hello
world
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

The `\hrulefill` is only to show the start/end of the environment `myenv` and most likely not needed in your application.

Although the proposed solution does not show the typewriter font, you can issue `\ttfamily` to achieve this (not `\texttt`).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the application a minor problem of Werner's solution is that if a line is longer than the texwith the continuation is not indented. Here is an alternative solution (and comparison with Werner's solution).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}
  {\begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\topsep}{3mm}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
    \small\ttfamily}
    \item[]\hrulefill\\}
  {\hrulefill\end{list}}

\newenvironment{myenvW}
  {\par\hrulefill\obeylines\small\ttfamily}
  {\hrulefill\par\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[6]
\begin{myenv}
  test\\
  \lipsum[6]
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{myenvW}
  test
  \lipsum[6]
\end{myenvW}
\end{document}
```

[image]